# When launching a JFrame it is completely black

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, server, jframe

I am trying to make a mock social media application where a user is able to create an account, with a password and user (doesn't have to be secure or anything) and stored in a server. They are able to create a profile with some rudimentary variables and set a profile picture. All using a GUI via JavaSwing. This is all being run off a server as well.

Login Client

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

//TODO: ADD WELCOME MESSAGE
//TODO: FIX MESSAGES TO SERVER BASED ON WHAT YOU WROTE IN GOOGLE DOCS

public class LoginClient extends JComponent implements Runnable {
    private static JTextField userLog;
    private static JTextField passLog;
    private static JTextField userCreate;
    private static JTextField passCreate;

    private static JButton loginButton;
    private static JButton createButton;
    LoginClient logClient;
    public static boolean bool = true;

    public static User receive;
    public static boolean loop = false;

    public static InputStream input;
    public static OutputStream output;

    public static ObjectOutputStream writer;
    public static ObjectInputStream reader;
    public static Socket socket;
    public static String username;

    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("");

        Container content = frame.getContentPane();
        content.setLayout(null);
        logClient = new LoginClient();
        content.add(logClient, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        content.add(logClient);
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        loginButton = new JButton("Login");
        createButton = new JButton("Create");
        userLog = new JTextField(25);
        passLog = new JTextField(25);
        userCreate = new JTextField(25);
        passCreate = new JTextField(25);

        userLog.setBounds(60, 100, 170, 30);
        content.add(userLog);

        passLog.setBounds(60, 160, 170, 30);
        content.add(passLog);

        loginButton.setBounds(100, 220, 100, 50);
        content.add(loginButton);

        userCreate.setBounds(360, 100, 170, 30);
        content.add(userCreate);

        passCreate.setBounds(360, 160, 170, 30);
        content.add(passCreate);

        createButton.setBounds(400, 220, 100, 50);
        content.add(createButton);

        JSeparator line = new JSeparator(JSeparator.VERTICAL);
        line.setBounds(300, 100, 5, 150);
        content.add(line);

        JLabel signInText = new JLabel("Sign In");
        signInText.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        signInText.setBounds(115, 30, 200, 50);
        content.add(signInText);

        JLabel createText = new JLabel("Create Account");
        createText.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        createText.setBounds(380, 30, 300, 50);
        content.add(createText);

        loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {

                    User anotherLog = new User(userLog.getText(), passLog.getText());
                    anotherLog.setPhase(0);
                    writer.writeObject(anotherLog);
                    writer.flush();
                    //writer.reset();
                    receive = (User) reader.readObject();
                    if(receive != null) {
                        System.out.println(receive);
                    }
                    if ((userLog.getText().equals("") || passLog.getText().equals(""))) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                "Please enter your username and password.",
                                "Null Login", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    } else if (receive.getUsername() == null) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                "Your account does not exist. Please Check your username and password.",
                                "Incorrect Login", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    } else if (receive.getUsername().equals(userLog.getText()) &&
                            !receive.getPassword().equals(passLog.getText())) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                "Your password is incorrect.",
                                "Incorrect Password", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    } else if (receive.getUsername().equals(userLog.getText()) &&
                            receive.getPassword().equals(passLog.getText())) {
                        //writer.writeObject(new User());
                        // writer.flush();
                        System.out.println("log done");
                        username = receive.getUsername();
                        MainClient main = new MainClient();
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(main);
                        main.setUsername(username);
                        frame.setVisible(false);
                    }

                } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ioException) {
                    ioException.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        createButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    User anotherCreate = new User(userCreate.getText(), passCreate.getText());
                    anotherCreate.setPhase(3);
                    writer.writeObject(anotherCreate);
                    writer.flush();

                    receive = (User) reader.readObject();

                    if ((userCreate.getText().equals("") || passCreate.getText().equals(""))) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                "Please enter a valid username and password.",
                                "Null Account Info", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                    else if (receive.getUsername() == null) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                "Your username has already been taken. Please enter another one.",
                                "Existing Account", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    } else if (receive.getUsername().equals(userCreate.getText())){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                "Your account has been created",
                                "Congratulations!", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                        return;
                    }
                } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ioException) {
                    ioException.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //all this goes in main driver class once we have it
        socket = new Socket("localhost", 4242);

        input = socket.getInputStream();
        output = socket.getOutputStream();
        writer = new ObjectOutputStream(output);
        reader = new ObjectInputStream(input);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new LoginClient());

    }
}
```

Main Client

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class MainClient extends JFrame implements ActionListener, Runnable {

    //instance data for the fields of the popup
    Container container = getContentPane();
    public static InputStream input;
    public static OutputStream output;

    JButton viewProfile = new JButton("View Profile");
    JButton editProfile = new JButton("Edit Profile");
    JButton createProfile = new JButton("Create/Edit Profile");
    JButton deleteProfile = new JButton("Delete Profile");

    JButton userSearch = new JButton("User Search");
    JButton importProfile = new JButton("Import Profile");
    JButton exportProfile = new JButton("Export Profile");
    JButton friends = new JButton("Friends List");
    JButton homeButton = new JButton("Home");

    public static String username;

    //constructor that calls the methods and generates the GUI
    public void run() {
        setTitle("Main Page");
        setVisible(true);
        setBounds(10, 10, 800, 600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setLayoutManager();
        setLocationAndSize();
        addComponents();
        addActionEvent();
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }


    //methods that initialize the popup fields
    public void setLayoutManager() {
        container.setLayout(null);
    }

    public void setLocationAndSize() {
        //center of the screen
        createProfile.setBounds(300, 180, 200, 100);
        viewProfile.setBounds(300, 280, 200, 100);

        //top left of screen
        userSearch.setBounds(50, 50, 150, 30);
        friends.setBounds(50,200,150,30);
        //bottom right and left of the screen
        importProfile.setBounds(50, 500, 150, 30);
        exportProfile.setBounds(600, 500, 150, 30);
    }

    public void addComponents() {
        container.add(viewProfile);
        container.add(editProfile);
        container.add(createProfile);
        container.add(deleteProfile);
        container.add(userSearch);
        container.add(importProfile);
        container.add(exportProfile);
        container.add(friends);
    }

    public void addActionEvent() {
        viewProfile.addActionListener(this);
        createProfile.addActionListener(this);
        friends.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            if (e.getSource() == viewProfile) {
                viewProfilePage viewProfilePage = new viewProfilePage();
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(viewProfilePage);
                viewProfilePage.setUsername(username);

            } else if (e.getSource() == createProfile) {
                createProfilePage createProfilePage = new createProfilePage();
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(createProfilePage);
                createProfilePage.setUsername(username);

            } else if (e.getSource() == friends) {
                FriendGUI friendGUI = new FriendGUI();
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(friendGUI);
                friendGUI.setUsername(username);
            }

        } catch (Exception g) {

            g.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Server

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server implements Runnable{

    protected int serverPort = 4242;
    protected ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    protected boolean isStopped = false;
    protected Thread runningThread = null;
    public Server(int port){
        this.serverPort = port;
    }
    public void run() {
        synchronized(this){
            this.runningThread = Thread.currentThread();
        }
        openServerSocket();
        while(!isStopped()){
            Socket clientSocket = null;
            try {
                clientSocket = this.serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("accepted");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if(isStopped()) {
                    System.out.println("Server Stopped.") ;
                    return;
                }
                throw new RuntimeException(
                        "Error accepting client connection", e);
            }
            new Thread(new ClientHandler(clientSocket)).start();
        }
        System.out.println("Server Stopped.") ;
    }


    private synchronized boolean isStopped() {
        return this.isStopped;
    }

    public synchronized void stop(){
        this.isStopped = true;
        try {
            this.serverSocket.close();
            System.out.println("closed");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error closing server", e);
        }
    }
    private void openServerSocket() {
        try {
            this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(this.serverPort);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot open port 4242", e);
        }
    }

}
```

server Driver

```
public class ServerDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server server = new Server(4242);
        new Thread(server).start();

    }
}
```

User class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * This is the User class which contains the building blocks of the base user of
 * our overall module.
 */
public class User implements Serializable {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private long phone;
    private String interest;
    private ArrayList<String> friendsList;
    private String aboutMe;
    private ArrayList<String> friendrequests;
    private ArrayList<String> incomingrequst;
    private int phase;

    /**
     * Constructor for brand new user. New users will have to manually add interests, friends, and
     * about me using setters.
     *
     */

    public User(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.name = null;
        this.age = 0;
        this.phone = 0;
        this.interest = null;
        this.friendsList = null;
        this.aboutMe = null;
        this.phase = 0;
    }
    public User(String username) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = null;
        this.name = null;
        this.age = 0;
        this.phone = 0;
        this.interest = null;
        this.friendsList = null;
        this.aboutMe = null;
        this.phase = 0;
    }
    public User() {
        this.username = null;
        this.password = null;
        this.name = null;
        this.age = 0;
        this.phone = 0;
        this.interest = null;
        this.friendsList = null;
        this.aboutMe = null;
        this.phase = 0;
    }

    public User(String username, String password, String name, int age, long phone) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        friendsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.aboutMe = null;
        this.phase = 0;
    }

    /**
     * This constructor is for a user who may have a prepopulated set all qualities.
     *
     * @param name: full name of user (string)
     * @param age: age of user (int)
     * @param phone: phone number of user (long)
     * @param interest: array list of interests (ArrayList<String>)
     * //@param  array list where each index is a friend (ArrayList<String>)
     * @param aboutMe: array list describing the user (ArrayList<String>)
     */
    public User(String username, String name, int age, long phone, String interest,
                String aboutMe) {
        this.username = username;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.interest = interest;
        this.friendsList = friendsList;
        this.aboutMe = aboutMe;
        this.phase = 0;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getFriendrequests() {
        return this.friendrequests;
    }

    public void setFriendrequests(ArrayList<String> friendrequests) {
        this.friendrequests = friendrequests;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getIncomingrequst() {
        return this.incomingrequst;
    }

    public void setIncomingrequst(ArrayList<String> incomingrequst) {
        this.incomingrequst = incomingrequst;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public long getPhone() {
        return this.phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(long phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getInterest() {
        return this.interest;
    }

    public void setInterest(String interest) {
        this.interest = interest;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getFriendsList() {
        return this.friendsList;
    }

    public void setFriendsList(ArrayList<String> friendsList) {
        this.friendsList = friendsList;
    }

    public String getAboutMe() {
        return this.aboutMe;
    }

    public void setAboutMe(String aboutMe) {
        this.aboutMe = aboutMe;
    }

    public int getPhase() {
        return this.phase;
    }

    public void setPhase(int phase) {
        this.phase = phase;
    }

    public User(File fileName) {
        FileReader fr = null;
        try {
            fr = new FileReader(fileName);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(fr);
        try {
            String line = bfr.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                this.username = line;
                line = bfr.readLine();
                this.password = line;
                line = bfr.readLine();
                this.name = line;
                line = bfr.readLine();
                this.age = Integer.parseInt(line);
                line = bfr.readLine();
                this.phone = Long.parseLong(line);
                line = bfr.readLine();

                this.interest = line;
                line = bfr.readLine();

                this.aboutMe = line;
                line = bfr.readLine();

               /*** ArrayList<String> interests = new ArrayList<String>();
                String interestArray[];
                interestArray = line.split(",");
                for (int i = 0; i < interestArray.length; i++) {
                    interests.add(interestArray[i]);
                }
                this.interest = interests; ***/

                 ArrayList<String> friendsList = new ArrayList<String>();
                String friendsArray[];
                friendsArray = line.split(",");
                for (int i = 0; i < friendsArray.length; i++) {
                    friendsList.add(friendsArray[i]);

                }
                this.friendsList = friendsList;

                /*** ArrayList<String> aboutMe = new ArrayList<String>();
                String aboutMeArray[];
                aboutMeArray = line.split(",");
                for (int i = 0; i < aboutMeArray.length; i++) {
                    aboutMe.add(aboutMeArray[i]);

                }
                this.aboutMe = aboutMe; ***/

                bfr.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Create profile class

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

class createProfilePage extends JFrame implements ActionListener, Runnable {
    Container container = getContentPane();

    static User user;
    public String username;

    JLabel name = new JLabel("Name: ");
    JTextField nameField = new JTextField();

    JLabel age = new JLabel("Age: ");
    JTextField ageField = new JTextField();

    JLabel interest = new JLabel("Interests: ");
    JTextField interestField = new JTextField();

    JLabel aboutMe = new JLabel("About me: ");
    JTextField aboutMeField = new JTextField();

    JLabel phoneNum = new JLabel("Phone Number: ");
    JTextField phoneNumberField = new JTextField();
    JLabel picLabel = new JLabel();

    JButton submit = new JButton("Save Profile");
    JButton deleteProfile = new JButton("Delete Profile");

    JButton uploadPic = new JButton("Upload Profile Picture");

    public static ObjectInputStream reader;
    public static ObjectOutputStream writer;
    public static Socket socket;
    public void run()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        //setting container
        setLayoutManager();
        setLocationAndSize();
        addComponents();
        addActionEvent();
        setVisible(true);
        setTitle("Create Profile");
        setSize(600, 500);
    }
    public void setLayoutManager() {
        container.setLayout(null);
    }
    public void setLocationAndSize()
    {
        //Setting location and Size of each components using setBounds() method.
        name.setBounds(50,100,100,30);
        age.setBounds(50,170,100,30);
        phoneNum.setBounds(50,240,100,30);
        interest.setBounds(50,310,100,30);
        aboutMe.setBounds(50,380,100,30);

        submit.setBounds(350, 240, 150, 30);
        deleteProfile.setBounds(350,310,150,30);
        uploadPic.setBounds(350,380,150,30);

        nameField.setBounds(150,100,150,30);
        ageField.setBounds(150,170,150,30);
        phoneNumberField.setBounds(150,240,150,30);
        interestField.setBounds(150,310,150,30);
        aboutMeField.setBounds(150,380,150,30);
        picLabel.setBounds(350, 50, 150, 150);
    }
    public void addComponents() {
        container.add(name);
        container.add(age);
        container.add(phoneNum);
        container.add(interest);
        container.add(aboutMe);
        container.add(nameField);
        container.add(ageField);
        container.add(phoneNumberField);
        container.add(interestField);
        container.add(aboutMeField);
        container.add(submit);
        container.add(deleteProfile);
        container.add(uploadPic);
        container.add(picLabel);
    }
    public void addActionEvent() {
        submit.addActionListener(this);
        deleteProfile.addActionListener(this);
        uploadPic.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == submit) {
            String name = nameField.getText();
            String age = ageField.getText();
            String phoneNum = phoneNumberField.getText();
            String interest = interestField.getText();
            String aboutMe = aboutMeField.getText();
            try {

                Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 4242);

                //creating user object to send to the server

                //TODO
                user = new User(username, name, Integer.valueOf(age),Long.valueOf(phoneNum), interest, aboutMe);

                writer = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                user.setPhase(1);
                writer.writeObject(user);

                reader = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                user = (User) reader.readObject();
                String username = user.getUsername();

               // User user = new User(username, name, Integer.valueOf(age),Long.valueOf(phoneNum), interest, aboutMe);
                setVisible(false);

            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException b) {
                b.printStackTrace();
            }



            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Profile Creation Successful");
        } else if (e.getSource() == deleteProfile) {
            String name = null;
            String age = null;
            String phoneNum = null;
            String interest = null;
            String aboutMe = null;

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Profile Deletion Successful");
        } else if (e.getSource() == uploadPic) {
            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
            int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(getParent());
            if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                try {
                    //getting file from directory
                    File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                    BufferedImage picture = ImageIO.read(file);
                    //sending image to server
                    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",4242);
                    writer = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    //String filename = file.toString();
                    ImageIO.write(picture, "png", byteArrayOutputStream);
                    byte[] size = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(byteArrayOutputStream.size()).array();
                    //writer.write(size);
                    // writer.write(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
                    //adds pic to screen
                    picLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(picture.getScaledInstance(100,100,Image.SCALE_FAST)));
                    add(picLabel);
                    //flushes outputstream and closes Socket
                    writer.flush();
                    //socket.close();
                    //sets picture

                } catch (IOException g) {
                    g.printStackTrace();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ERROR");
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

View Profile class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
class viewProfilePage extends JFrame implements Runnable
{
    JLabel profilePic = new JLabel();
    Container container = getContentPane();
    static User user;
    JLabel about = new JLabel("About me:");
    JTextArea aboutMe;

    JTextField name;
    JTextField age;
    JTextField interestField;
    JTextField phoneNumberField;

    public static ObjectInputStream reader;
    public static ObjectOutputStream writer;
    public static Socket socket;
    public static String username;

    public void run()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayoutManager();
        setVisible(true);

        try {
            loadProfilePic();

            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 4242);
            writer = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            User anotherUser = new User(username);
            anotherUser.setPhase(0);
            writer.writeObject(anotherUser);
            reader = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            user = (User) reader.readObject();


            //fills in section of Profile
            String aboutMeSection = user.getAboutMe();
            aboutMe = new JTextArea(aboutMeSection, 30,30);

            String interestSection = user.getInterest();
            interestField = new JTextField(interestSection);

            String nameSpace = user.getName();
            name = new JTextField(nameSpace);

            String ageSpace = String.valueOf(user.getAge());
            age = new JTextField(ageSpace);

            String phoneNumSpace = String.valueOf(user.getPhone());

            //setting bounds
            phoneNumberField = new JTextField(phoneNumSpace);
            aboutMe.setBounds(150,50,100,200);
            name.setBounds(150,20,100,30);
            interestField.setBounds(150,250,100,200);
            age.setBounds( 300,20,100,30);
            phoneNumberField.setBounds(400,20,100,30);
            profilePic.setBounds(350, 50, 150, 150);
            //addint to container

            container.add(name);
            container.add(interestField);
            container.add(age);
            container.add(phoneNumberField);
            container.add(profilePic);
        } catch ( Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setTitle("View Profile");
        setSize(800, 800);
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public void setLayoutManager() {
        container.setLayout(null);
    }

    public void loadProfilePic() throws Exception {
        JLabel profilePic = new JLabel();
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 4242);
        ClientHandler hand = new ClientHandler(socket);

        profilePic.setIcon(new ImageIcon(hand.getImage().getScaledInstance(100,100,Image.SCALE_FAST)));
        add(profilePic);
    }
}
```

Comment: However, when I'm trying to view a created profile, the JFrame is just completely black. Can anyone tell me why? Specifically, it is the ViewProfile class that is causing the problems. I comment on loadProfilePic() method and it works, but now can't figure out to display the image. 
I understand this is a lot of code to go through. Thank you for any help/suggestion I am very appreciative for any help.

Comment: You're block the event dispatching thread, so nothing is getting painted. Start by looking at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and may be [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for a possible solution

Comment: `static` is not a object communication mechanism, you should avoid using it in this context. And you really should take the time to learn how to use [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) - it will save you a lot of time and effort and sanity

Comment: And, you might want to consider a [mcve] next time